# GORM Change time format in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go, datetime-format, go-gorm

I have a problem with time in postgresql table with generic GORM model

```
   gorm.Model
```

with fields

```
    type Model struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time `sql:"index"`
}
```

all dates in table have format 2020-04-21 22:05:07.067446
Please Can I change to timstamp(LONG) or something without .067446

Thanks for any Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BeforeCreate](https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html#Creating-an-object) and [BeforeUpdate](https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html#Updating-an-object) hook for `gorm.Model` to manually set the value for the database.
Create `BaseModel` since you can't use type receiver for other package type.

```
type BaseModel struct {
    gorm.Model
}
```

Then manually set the value `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt` without nanoseconds

```
func (b *BaseModel) BeforeCreate() (err error) {
    b.CreatedAt = time.Unix(time.Now().Unix(), 0) // Calculate without nanosec
    return
}

func (b *BaseModel) BeforeUpdate() (err error) {
    b.UpdatedAt = time.Unix(time.Now().Unix(), 0) // Calculate without nanosec
    return
}
```

And then use BaseModel in your DB Model

```
type Data struct {
    BaseModel
    Name string
}
```

Comment: Did you try this solution ?

Comment: yes, and when i want to save long values? now i have in DB 2020-05-08 19:43:30.000000

Comment: Did you mean you want both features like long value also ? If yes then you can use  BeforeCreate and BeforeUpdate hook only for a Model .like `func (b *Data) BeforeCreate() (err error)`